# What are the meanings of `id` and `protocol_id`?

Tags: chainspec

When we use `ChainSpec::from_genesis`, we need to pass some string to these fields.

And these fields are not documented. So, how do we deal with these fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`protocol_id` was used earlier as some identifier for networking streams. Each network stream is sending this identifier on opening, so that the stream can be redirected to the correct protocol implementation. This `protocol_id` was used to create unique protocol identifiers per chain. As nodes from Acala for example can also connect to nodes from Polkadot, they would not even try to open the sync protocol because the protocol doesn't identifier doesn't match. Recently we "soft-deprecated" the `protocol_id`. Substrate will now take the genesis hash of your chain to make these protocol identifiers unique per chain.

TLDR for `protocol_id`: Use some unique string for identifying your chain protocols.

`id` is mainly used to create things like the base path where your database etc is stored. So, the `id` should may not contain spaces etc to make navigation in folders of your chain "easier". If you for example look at the `Kusama` chain spec you will see that the name is `Kusama`, but the `id` is `ksmcc3`. This `ksmcc3` stands for the Kusama chain candidate 3 as it took three different genesis to the final Kusama chain we have nowadays.

TLDR for `id`: Use some simple unique identifier for your chain that is "terminal friendly".

Comment: If you could add these to the `struct` field document. That would be great!